# Able to get response data but label is not shown in the dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

When I choose a country, I want to automatically get the city from DB and render it in the dropdown. I chose country and was able to get the response for the state (as the console output)

[image: console.log]

but not showing in the dropdown.

When I selected the empty option and posted the form, the state was added correctly.

[image: post operation and not showing state names in dropdown]

[image: after post operation, get operation]

person-add.component.html

```
<label>Country</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-space">
    <select  formControlName="country" (ngModelChange)="onSelect($event)" id="">
      <option value="" disabled selected> Choose Country</option>
      <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country.id" >
          {{country.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<label>State</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-space">
    <select  formControlName="state" id="">
      <option  value="" disabled selected>Choose State</option>
      <option *ngFor="let state of states"  [ngValue]="state.id" >
          {{state.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

person-add.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.countries = response.data
      }
    )
    this.createPerson();
  }

  createPerson() {
    this.personAddForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        name: ["", Validators.required],
        surname: ["", Validators.required],
        age: ["", Validators.required],
        country: ["", Validators.required],
        state: ["", Validators.required]
      }
    )
  }

  add() {
    if (this.personAddForm.valid) {
      let createPerson = { name: this.personAddForm.value.name, surname: this.personAddForm.value.surname, age: this.personAddForm.value.age, countryId: this.personAddForm.value.country, stateId: this.personAddForm.value.state }
      this.peopleService.addPerson(createPerson).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response.message)
          this.personAddForm.reset()
          this.router.navigate([""])
        }
      )
    } else {

    }
  }

  onSelect(countryId : any) {
    this.stateService.getStatesAccordingToCountryId(countryId).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.states = response.data;
        console.log(response.data)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

I expect to show data (label) on the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your console output, there is no `name` property, but `stateName`.

Change the property name to `stateName`.

```
<option *ngFor="let state of states"  [ngValue]="state.id" >
    {{state.stateName}}
</option>
```